# Using RichTextBlock in FlipView in Metro Style App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using standard Visual Studio templates and I have a ItemsDetailPage that contains a FlipView with a RichTextBlock in its DataTemplate.

I want to set the RichTextBlock block to my custom Paragraphs generated in text. I think there is no way to bind RichTextBlocks Block in XAML so I am using code behind. In the Loaded event of RichTextBlock I set its Block, that works ok. But the problem is, the Loaded event gets called only once when the page is displayed. When I "flip" to another item, the selected item of the FlipView changes but the Loaded event does not get called again (I think this is ok).

I tried setting the RichTextBlock in the FlipViews SelectionChanged item but that does not work.

```
var ind = this.flipView.SelectedIndex;

        var flipViewItem = this.flipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(flipView.SelectedIndex);

        if (flipViewItem != null)
        {               
            var scroller = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(flipViewItem);
            var tb = scroller.FindDescendantByName("richTextColumns").FindDescendantByName("richTextBlock") as RichTextBlock;
            SetRichContent(tb, (flipView.SelectedItem as ArticleViewModel).HtmlContent);               
        }
```

The SetRichContent gets called, sets the RichTextBlocks Blocks but visually they do not change and after a few flips, the whole app crashes without any additional information.

So my question is, how do I get my own code called on the RichTextBlock with each flip (seleced item change)?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind rich text boxes. Make sure your data context is set properly. We need to see more code to make an appropriate answer.

```
<RichTextColumns>
     <RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="400" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>

     <RichTextBlock Width="400">
         <Paragraph>
             <Run Text="{Binding Content}"/>
         </Paragraph>
     </RichTextBlock>
</RichTextColumns>
```

Comment: That is binding the whole Content to one run as in the template in VS. I need to bind multiple paragraphs and runs

Comment: Try using multiple Runs for each paragraph that you need.

Comment: the question is how to acces the RichTextBlock in the DataTemplate witch SelectedItem change, not how to add Runs to a RichTextBlock, that is trivial